# How to pass macros as arguments to other macros

Tags: macros

I have a use case where I need to do some repeated mathematical computation within my document (as in, computing radii for many different circles in a TikZ loop). And even after many years writing documents in LaTeX, I just can't figure out the best or right way to pass macros to other macros as arguments.  Below I've included a very simple example of the kind of thing I am talking about.

I'm pretty sure this has to do with macro expansion, how macros are not the same as functions, and how TeX inserts a space after the control codes \MyAdd. And I've found a few detailed explanations about what is going on under the hood.  What I have not been able to find is a solution.  What is the simplest, yet most correct way to take the output of one macro, potentially store it in a "variable," and pass either the full macro or the variable to another macro for further processing?

Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xfp}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyAdd}{m m}{
  \fpeval{#1 + #2}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMult}{m m}{
  \fpeval{#1 * #2}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyArgs}{m m}{
%% Inspect arguments as passed
  \immediate\write20{Arg 1:  #1}
  \immediate\write20{Arg 2:  #2}
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

Correct: \MyAdd{1}{3}\\
Correct: \MyMult{4}{7}\\

%% Store results as macros themselves
\def\factA{\MyAdd{1}{3}}
\def\factB{\MyAdd{4}{7}}

Correct: \factA \\

% The next two lines generate the following errors:
%  - Erroneous variable \fpeval used!
%  - Missing * inserted.
%  - Invalid operation fp_to_decimal(nan)

% \MyMult{\factA}{\factB}\\ %error
% \MyMult{\MyAdd{1}{3}}{\MyAdd{4}{7}}\\ %error

\MyArgs{\factA}{\factB}
%% Writes the following to the log.  Note the space after \MyAdd
% Arg 1: \MyAdd {1}{3}
% Arg 2: \MyAdd {4}{7}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space after `\MyAdd` in the output of `\MyArgs` is completely standard. Any control word that sneaks in `\write` operation is always followed by a space.

Why? Suppose you have `\write20{\relax and \relax}`. By rule, there is ***no*** space after the first `\relax` when tokens are formed. If TeX didn't add a space after control words, the output would become

```
\relaxand \relax
```

which is a problem, isn't it?

You should worry of several other spaces you add in the code. Your first definition is completely equivalent to

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyAdd}{m m}{ \fpeval{#1 + #2} }
```

because an endline is converted to a space. Spaces between argument specifiers in `\NewDocumentCommand` are ignored. Not ignored are spaces in the replacement text. However, if you write the code as you did but after `\ExplSyntaxOn`, endline and spaces would be ignored.

The main problem of your code is another, though.

You should use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` for your `\MyAdd` and `\MyMult` commands. And `\edef` if you want to store the result in a control sequence.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xfp}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\MyAdd}{m m}{%
  \fpeval{#1 + #2}%
}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\MyMult}{m m}{%
  \fpeval{#1 * #2}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyArgs}{m m}{%
%% Inspect arguments as passed
  \immediate\write20{Arg 1:  #1}%
  \immediate\write20{Arg 2:  #2}%
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

Correct: \MyAdd{1}{3}\\
Correct: \MyMult{4}{7}

%% Store results as macros themselves
\edef\factA{\MyAdd{1}{3}}
\edef\factB{\MyAdd{4}{7}}

Correct: \factA

% The next two lines generate the following errors:
%  - Erroneous variable \fpeval used!
%  - Missing * inserted.
%  - Invalid operation fp_to_decimal(nan)

\MyMult{\factA}{\factB}
\MyMult{\MyAdd{1}{3}}{\MyAdd{4}{7}}

\MyArgs{\factA}{\factB}
%% Writes the following to the log.  Note the space after \MyAdd
% Arg 1: \MyAdd {1}{3}
% Arg 2: \MyAdd {4}{7}

\end{document}
```

If you define `\MyAdd` and `\MyMult` with `\NewDocumentCommand`, they will be `\protected`, so they don't expand inside `\edef` and so this expanded definition would do nothing at all.

Comment: Thanks, this was quite helpful.  A follow-up question: Is it correct to say that, in general, bracketing the xparse command definitions with \ExplSyntaxOn and \ExplSyntaxOff is more "forgiving" with spaces, and that I should make that standard practice? Are there any downsides?  Second follow-up question: Once I do add the ExplSyntax macros, whether I use def or edef, or NewExpandableDocument Command or not, does not seem to make a difference.  So I am still a little confused about which to use where.

Answer (score 1):

As you indicated yourself, there are some spurious spaces. I removed them by adding `%`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xfp}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyAdd}{m m}{%
  \fpeval{#1 + #2}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMult}{m m}{%
  \fpeval{#1 * #2}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyArgs}{m m}{%
%% Inspect arguments as passed
  \typeout{Arg 1:  #1}%
  \typeout{Arg 2:  #2}%
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

Correct: \MyAdd{1}{3}\par
Correct: \MyMult{4}{7}\par

%% Store results as macros themselves
\def\factA{\MyAdd{1}{3}}
\def\factB{\MyAdd{4}{7}}
Correct: \factA \par
Correct: \factB \par

% The next two lines generate the following errors:
%  - Erroneous variable \fpeval used!
%  - Missing * inserted.
%  - Invalid operation fp_to_decimal(nan)

\MyMult{\factA}{\factB}\par %error
\MyMult{\MyAdd{1}{3}}{\MyAdd{4}{7}}\par %error

\MyArgs{\factA}{\factB}
%% Writes the following to the log.  Note the space after \MyAdd
% Arg 1: \MyAdd {1}{3}
% Arg 2: \MyAdd {4}{7}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, however, that instead of

```
\def\factA{\MyAdd{1}{3}}
\def\factB{\MyAdd{4}{7}}
```

you probably want

```
\edef\factA{\MyAdd{1}{3}}
\edef\factB{\MyAdd{4}{7}}
```

because further nesting will cause troubles if you keep using `\def`s.

Comment: You should try the code you propose: `\edef` and `\def` would make no difference at all. I'm sure you can guess why even without reading my answer.

Comment: Obviously you did not read my answer. Besides, you recommend using `\edef` in your writeup.

Comment: I read your answer carefully. You didn't notice the important change I made to the definition of `\MyAdd` and `\MyMult`. You obviously didn't try `\edef` with your unchanged code, did you? You'll have a surprise if you do.

Comment: That did solve the problem. Much appreciated.